# Add different parallel lines on a canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am trying to add different layers (i.e two parallel lines to canvas). I implemented the code with one pair of parallel lines of one color. Now I need to add different color lines without removing the previous lines. Attached is the js fiddle. Please help. After clicking layers. you can draw layers on the canvas.

```
    var oImageBuffer = document.createElement('img');
  var oCanvas=document.getElementById("SetupImageCanvas");
  var o2DContext=oCanvas.getContext("2d");
  var oRect = {};
  var oROI = {};
  var oLayers = new Array();
  var bDragging = false;
  var bSetROI = false;
  var bSetLayers = false;
  InitMouseEvents();
  var oSelect = document.getElementById("ImageList");
  oSelect.onchange=function() {
    changeCanvasImage(oSelect[oSelect.selectedIndex].value);
  }


  // Canvas event handlers (listeners).
  function InitMouseEvents() {
    oCanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', MouseDownEvent, false);
    oCanvas.addEventListener('mouseup', MouseUpEvent, false);
    oCanvas.addEventListener('mousemove', MouseMoveEvent, false);
    oCanvas.addEventListener('mouseout', MouseOutEvent, false);
  }
  function MouseDownEvent(e) {
    oRect.startX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    oRect.startY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    bDragging = true;
  }
  function MouseUpEvent() {
    bDragging = false;
  }
  function MouseOutEvent() {
    document.getElementById("MouseCoords").innerHTML="";
  }
  function MouseMoveEvent(e) {
    if (bDragging) {
      oRect.w = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) - oRect.startX;
      oRect.h = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop) - oRect.startY;
      oCanvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0,0,oCanvas.width, oCanvas.height);
      var oROI = document.getElementById("btnROI");
      if (oROI.checked) {
        SetROI();
      }
      var oLayer = document.getElementById("btnLAYER");
      if (oLayer.checked) {
        SetLayer();
      }
    }

    if (bSetROI) {
      DrawROI();
    }
    if (bSetLayers) {
      DrawLayers();
    }
    // Display the current mouse coordinates.
    ShowCoordinates(e);
  }

  function ShowCoordinates(e) {
    x=e.clientX;
    y=e.clientY;
    document.getElementById("MouseCoords").innerHTML="(" + x + "," + y + ") " + document.getElementById('txtPatchCount').value;
  }

  // Interactively draw ROI rectangle(s) on the canvas.
  function SetROI() {
    bSetROI = true;
    oROI.startX = oRect.startX;
    oROI.startY = oRect.startY;
    oROI.w = oRect.w;
    oROI.h = oRect.h;    
  }
  function DrawROI() {
    o2DContext.lineWidth=1.5;
    o2DContext.strokeStyle = '#0F0';
    o2DContext.strokeRect(oROI.startX, oROI.startY, oROI.w, oROI.h);

    var iPatches = document.getElementById('txtPatchCount').value;
    o2DContext.beginPath();
    var iTop = oROI.startY;
    var iBottom = oROI.startY + oROI.h;
    var iLeft = oROI.startX;
    var iX = iLeft;
    for (var iPatch=1; iPatch<iPatches; ++iPatch) {
      iX = iLeft + iPatch*oROI.w/iPatches;
      o2DContext.moveTo(iX, iTop);
      o2DContext.lineTo(iX, iBottom);
    }
    o2DContext.lineWidth=0.25;
    o2DContext.stroke();
  }

  // Interactively draw layer boundaries on the canvas.
  function SetLayer() {
    bSetLayers = true;
    oLayers.length = 0;
    oLayers.push(oRect.startY);
    oLayers.push(oRect.startY + oRect.h);
  }
  function DrawLayers() {
    o2DContext.lineWidth=0.25;
    o2DContext.strokeStyle = '#F00';

    o2DContext.beginPath();
    var iY = oLayers[0];
    var iLeft = 0;
    var iRight = oCanvas.width;
    for (var iLayer=0; iLayer<oLayers.length; ++iLayer) {
      iY = oLayers[iLayer];
      o2DContext.moveTo(iLeft, iY);
      o2DContext.lineTo(iRight, iY);
      o2DContext.stroke();
    }
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AhdJr/30/

Comment: Create an array to save each new layer(var layers=[]). In mouseup the new layer has been fully defined so add it to the layers array (layers.push(oLayers). In DrawLayers draw every layer in the layers array.

Comment: Can you elaborate more please

Comment: Sure, I added an example in the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array to save each new layer and draw all the saved layers.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/UfuDX/

[image]

**mousedown**

- set the isDown flag to indicate the user is dragging
- save the "Y" position where the drag started

**mouseup**

- clear the isDown flag to indicate the drag has completed
- Save the "Y" positions of both parallel lines plus the current color

**mousemove**

- draw all the previously saved parallel lines
- draw the current (temporary) parallel line

Here's code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var isDown=false;
    var startY;

    var layers=[];
    var currentColor="black";

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      currentColor=randomColor();
      isDown=true;
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      isDown=false;
      layers.push({y1:startY,y2:mouseY,color:currentColor});
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      isDown=false;
      layers.push({y1:startY,y2:mouseY,color:currentColor});
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      if(!isDown){return;}
      e.preventDefault();
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      drawAll();
      hLine(startY,currentColor);
      hLine(mouseY,currentColor);
    }

    function drawAll(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        for(var i=0;i<layers.length;i++){
            layer=layers[i];
            hLine(layer.y1,layer.color);
            hLine(layer.y2,layer.color);
        }
    }

    function hLine(y,color){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0,y);
        ctx.lineTo(canvas.width,y);
        ctx.strokeStyle=color;
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    function randomColor(){ 
        return('#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});



}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @markE I did according to the solution but still I can draw one line. Can you please look what is the problem in this.
http://jsfiddle.net/AhdJr/41/

Comment: I can see different colors in the line.

Comment: You need to *save the previous layers* and redraw them along with the new "temporary" layer.  See my example code where the completed pairs are put into the layers[] array.  Cheers!

Comment: I tried the same thing in my example. can you please point out the error. thanks

Comment: can you please look into this.

Comment: You were accidentally clearing the oLayers array.  You were also using the variable oLayers both as the array and as the checkbox reference.  You were sometimes using the oRect.startX property when you s/b using startY.  Anyway, here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/J9Ahr/  Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks @markE but now the ROI is not working properly. If you are drawing the region of interest alone. it will not work.

Comment: The technique to do your ROI is the same as for layers: save the ROI coordinates and redraw it each time the canvas is redrawn..

Comment: ok let me try this. If I am drawing ROi when Layers is clicked is working but alone ROI is not working.

Comment: will it be possible for you  to help in this.

Comment: Don't say I never did anything for you!  Do I get credit?  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/b84pZ/

Comment: We cannot have more than one ROI but multiple layers should be there.

Comment: Uncheck and Disable #btnROI when you don't want your users to add ROI to a layer.

Comment: Hi @markE one more thing. after unchecking the ROI the patches in ROI disappears when you draw layers to it.\

Comment: I thought that's what you said you wanted?? :-/ I don't know your design requirements!  Ok...the patchCount property in the layer object always controls if the ROI will be drawn.  If patchCount>0 the ROI is drawn. If patchCount=0 then no ROI is drawn.  So use the patchCount property to control exactly when you want the ROI to be drawn.

Comment: yes thats correct I am not talking about that . I am talking about the divisions in the rectangle. like if the patch count is 3 there will be 3 partitions in the rectangle. If we uncheck the ROi and start drawing layers on the canvas the partition disappears but the rectangle remains. I want the partition to be there as well.

Comment: Did you spot the error?  One `layer` reference was missing when drawing the ROI.  Change to this: var x=layer.x1 + I *w / layer.patchCount;

Comment: Hi Is there a chance that we can limit the ROI to be drawn only once.